# jquery.validate.1.9.js - validation ignoring things not listed in regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have a simple form with 10 or so fields on it. Two of those fields are "First Name" and "Last Name". The validate rules are pretty simple for them, but aren't really working.

The code:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.1.9.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.tinysort.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Add Text Only
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("TextOnly", function (value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        }, "Only Characters from A-Z.");
    });

    $("#form").validate({
        ignore: ".ignore",
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            "FirstName": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 100,
                TextOnly: "^[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\ \-\.]+$"
            },
            "LastName": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 100,
                TextOnly: "^[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\ \-\.]+$"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "FirstName": {
                required: "Please enter the First Name."
              , minlength: "First Name must be at least 2 characters."
              , maxlength: "First Name may be no more than 100 characters."
              , TextOnly: "The First Name may contain only letters, numbers, spaces, dashes '-', periods '.', and parentheses '(' ')'."
            },
            "LastName": {
                required: "Please enter the Last Name."
              , minlength: "Last Name must be at least 2 characters."
              , maxlength: "Last Name may be no more than 100 characters."
              , TextOnly: "The Last Name may contain only letters, numbers, spaces, dashes '-', periods '.', and parentheses '(' ')'."
            }}
        ////Commenting the following out places the errors under each field, instead of in a single area.
        , errorLabelContainer: $("#form div.error")
    });
```

The TextOnly validator works for a bunch of things, but what's strange to me is that it allows certain characters to pass through and doesn't call out an error. For instance, I can type "***" in the First/Last Name fields, and it accepts that as valid content.

Characters that "pass" that shouldn't:
! # $ % & * ' " ,

So if I type "as $%&*'"," in the field, it passes validation, regardless of the regex validation being done.

Comment: Firstly, update jQuery Validate to the latest version.

Comment: Updated to 1.9, issue still exists.

Comment: there's a more recent one, @Sparky?

Comment: 1.9 is very old.  Version 1.13.1 is the most recent.  See:  [http://jqueryvalidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a method called `TextOnly` but the function itself has nothing to do with that... it's just a regex evaluator. If you're going to call it `TextOnly`, you might as well build your "text-only" regex into it.

Otherwise, [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js) already contains a rule for evaluating a regex passed into it called `pattern`...

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        FirstName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 100,
            pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\ \-\.]+$/
        }
    },
    messages: {
        FirstName: {
            pattern: "Only Characters from A-Z."
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/htb48ebu/**

Comment: The "aditional-methods.js" that is listed is actually a home-made one, with  custom methods in it. Our "TextOnly" method is a regex eval. Looking at the one that is in the link you posted, it's pretty much the same as ours, so the question of why the validation fails is still up in the air.

Comment: In the end, I decided to use the pattern method from additional-methods.js. However, given the nature of our own internally named version of additional methods, I've just added it to ours with a comment as to where it came from.